# How to watch for vuex state?

Tags: vue.js

I need do fire a function within component when my vuex state data change, but it does not work , is there any wrong usage about watch hook for vuex?

```
const state = {
     currentQueryParameter:[],

 };

 const mutations = {
    currentQueryParameter(state,info){
         state.currentQueryParameter[info.index]=info.value
          Vue.set(info, info.index,   info.value);
}
}
```

in component

```
  watch: {
       '$store.state.currentQueryParameter': function() {
        console.log("changed")
        this.getData()
  }
 },
```

Comment: You should use a `getter` in Vuex - and then watch this getter (preferably injecting it in the component with the help of `mapGetters`)

Answer (score 10):

What you are doing is technically correct and will work.

However several thing are still going wrong:

1. If you want your state to be reactive you need to fill Arrays with native array methods (`.push(), .splice()` etc). `Vue.set()` is only used to set Object properties.
2. You are watching `currentQueryParameter`, which is an Array. Its value does not change through your mutation - it stays the same Array. If you want to watch nested elements as well, you need to use the `deep` flag in your watcher, like so:

```js
watch: {
  '$store.state.currentQueryParameter': {
    deep: true,
    handler(newVal) {
      console.log('queryParameter changed');
    }
  }
}
```

3. I don't know what you are trying to do with this one in your mutation:
   `Vue.set(info, info.index,   info.value);` but you should not mutate the properties you pass to a function.